# Python/Pandas - drop observations from a dataset

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, if-statement, drop-down-menu

I am new using pandas and I would really appreciate if someone can help me to solve this question.

I have the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
# sample dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({
  'Price': [-3000, -262, 150, -3000, -262, 150, -3000, -262, 150, -3000, -262, 0],
  'Volume': [8133, 28287, 19289, 20242, 19428, 28322, 18147, 17234, 12133,18147, 17234, 12133],})

print('Raw dataframe:')
print(df, '\n')
```

I want to get rid of those observations were the number of times that ¨price¨ appears is not equal to 4. In this example: -3000 and -262 are the only price observations that appear 4 times, therefore I would like just to keep those.

I would be really thankful if someone can help me.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with `size` for count per groups to Series with same size like original `df`, so possible filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[df.groupby('Price')['Price'].transform('size') == 4]
```

Or use [`DataFrameGroupBy.filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.filter.html), but it should be slowier in large DataFrames:

```
df = df.groupby('Price').filter(lambda x: len(x) == 4)
```

Or [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
df = df[df['file'].map(df['file'].value_counts()) == 4]
```

---

```
print (df)
    Price  Volume
0   -3000    8133
1    -262   28287
3   -3000   20242
4    -262   19428
6   -3000   18147
7    -262   17234
9   -3000   18147
10   -262   17234
```

Answer (score 1):

you can  also use [`Series.value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) + [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
df[df['Price'].map(df['Price'].value_counts()) == 4)]
```

---

```
    Price  Volume
0   -3000    8133
1    -262   28287
3   -3000   20242
4    -262   19428
6   -3000   18147
7    -262   17234
9   -3000   18147
10   -262   17234
```